# Occur "OSError: Could not write record batch to stream" when write table using flight

Tags: python, pyarrow

I got a OSError when using flight to send data, and I got nothing useful information.

The basic info is:

```
python version 3.7.9
pyarrow version 0.17.1
```

The code is :

```
writer, reader = client.do_put(FlightDescriptor.for_path(*paths), schema)
writer.write_table(table)
result: Buffer = reader.read()
writer.close()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyarrow/ipc.pxi", line 240, in pyarrow.lib._CRecordBatchWriter.write_table
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
OSError: Could not write record batch to stream:
```

Comment: Hey @Long.zhao, usually this means the connection was broken somehow. Is there any more output? Otherwise, could you try running with these environment variables set and post the output? `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=http`

Comment: Thanks, I have found reason, as you said, I connected to a stopped service.

Comment: Please note pyarrow 0.17.1 is very old. 2.0.0 is available and 3.0.0 should be out soon.